# Python Tkinter start and stop button for a loop. I need a start and stop button for a loop

Tags: python, loops, button, tkinter

This is the code that i want 4 LED's to on then off after each other but they can be turned off and on by a GUI Start and Stop Button. I'm new the python and coding. i have look around and i can't seem to find a fix for my problem.

```
from Tkinter import *
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import sys
import time

##Setup
#GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
#Window
led = Tk()
led.title("LED Controller")
led.geometry("345x200+385+350")
#Title
title = Label(text="My LED Controller",fg="purple")
title.pack()

#Pin 7 = Front Left
GPIO.setup(7,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(7, GPIO.LOW)

#Pin 11 = Front Right
GPIO.setup(11,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(11, GPIO.LOW)

#Pin 13 = Back Left
GPIO.setup(13,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(13, GPIO.LOW)

#Pin 15 = Back Right
GPIO.setup(15,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(15, GPIO.LOW)

###Flash
##Define Loop/Flashing
#Flash
    def flash_1():
    while True: 
            if flashButton_1:
                GPIO.output(7, GPIO.HIGH)
                print "Pin 7 High"
                time.sleep(1)
                GPIO.output(7, GPIO.LOW)
                print "Pin 7 Low"
                GPIO.output(11, GPIO.HIGH)
                print "Pin 11 High"
                time.sleep(1)
                GPIO.output(11, GPIO.LOW)
                print "Pin 11 Low"
                GPIO.output(13, GPIO.HIGH)
                print "Pin 13 High"
                time.sleep(1)
                GPIO.output(13, GPIO.LOW)
                print "Pin 13 Low"
                GPIO.output(15, GPIO.HIGH)
                print "Pin 15 High"
                time.sleep(1)
                GPIO.output(15, GPIO.LOW)
                print "Pin 15 Low"

###Pack/Placement of buttons
##Flash
#Flash 1 Start
flashButton_1 = Button(led, text="Flash On", fg="red", command=flash_1)
flashButton_1.place(x=5,y=100)

#Loop Command
led.mainloop()

#Cleanup Command
GPIO.cleanup()
```

Answer (score 1):

`flash_1` is a function that never ends. So, it never returns the program flow control to a main event loop. Without event loop GUI does not refresh and freezes. It seems a similar question: [Python advice using delays with tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15615760/python-advice-using-delays-with-tkinter?rq=1)